# Defining Variable in Dropdown fails

Tags: javascript, html, function, drop-down-menu

I am creating my first website.

Firefox-Console: "Speed is not defined", but why? (The values of "myvalues" are data for chart.js diagram.)

Edit:

```
var speed = "50";

window.test = function(e){

if(e.value=="Motor1"){
    alert(e.value);
     speed = "50";//call here any function
}
else if(e.value=="Motor2"){
    alert(e.value);
    speed = "30";//call here any function       
}
else if(e.value == "Motor3"){
    alert(e.value);
   speed = "90";//call here any function
}} 
   var myvalues = new Array();
   myvalues.push(speed);
   myvalues.push("10");
   myvalues.push("10");
   myvalues.push("10");
   myvalues.push("10");
   myvalues.push("10");
   myvalues.push("10");
   myvalues.push("10");
   myvalues.push("10"); 




      var data = {
       labels: ["Top-Speed", "Acceleration", "Cost", "Durability", "H", "R", "W", "T"],
    datasets: [

        {
            fillColor: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.31)",
            strokeColor: "rgb(221, 221, 221)",
            pointColor : "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
            pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
            borderWidth : "5000000000000",
            backgroundColor: "rgb(221, 221, 221)",
            data : myvalues 
        }
    ]
};



  var ctx = $("#canvas")[0].getContext("2d");
    var TestChart = new Chart(ctx, { type: 'radar',
                                     data: data,
                                     options: options});

    new Chart(ctx).Radar(data,options);  
  </script>
```

So here I declared both variables in global scope, right? I don´t get any error message by console anymore, but my chart does not show any data. If I define var speed ="50" in global scope, it shows the entered data. So the function to change var speed does not work. I don´t know why.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Your var is not in the scope!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring `speed` variable inside `If` scope.

Try with this

```
window.test = function(e){
var speed;
if(e.value=="Motor1"){
    alert(e.value);
     speed = "50";//call here any function
}
else if(e.value=="Motor2"){
    alert(e.value);
    speed = "30";//call here any function       
}
else if(e.value == "Motor3"){
    alert(e.value);
   speed = "90";//call here any function
} 
   var myvalues = new Array();
   myvalues.push(speed);
   myvalues.push("10");
   myvalues.push("10");
   myvalues.push("10");
   myvalues.push("10");
   myvalues.push("10");
   myvalues.push("10");
   myvalues.push("10");
   myvalues.push("10"); 
}
```

**EDIT:**

Your edited code does not work because `window.test` is a function, and it does not execute procedural with the document. It just creates a function which can be invoked at any point, but does not invoke it. Since `myvalues` variable is sent as data source upon page load, it will not have proper speed, cause you invoked `window.test` function **after** the graph has been initialized.

You should place your graph initialization code inside the function, so it gets executed with the rest of the code.
Solution:

```
window.test = function(e) {
    var speed = "1"; //some default value

    if (e.value == "Motor1") {
        alert(e.value);
        speed = "50"; //call here any function
    } else if (e.value == "Motor2") {
        alert(e.value);
        speed = "30"; //call here any function       
    } else if (e.value == "Motor3") {
        alert(e.value);
        speed = "90"; //call here any function
    }
    var myvalues = new Array();
    myvalues.push(speed);
    myvalues.push("10");
    myvalues.push("10");
    myvalues.push("10");
    myvalues.push("10");
    myvalues.push("10");
    myvalues.push("10");
    myvalues.push("10");
    myvalues.push("10");




    var data = {
        labels: ["Top-Speed", "Acceleration", "Cost", "Durability", "H", "R", "W", "T"],
        datasets: [

            {
                fillColor: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.31)",
                strokeColor: "rgb(221, 221, 221)",
                pointColor: "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                borderWidth: "5000000000000",
                backgroundColor: "rgb(221, 221, 221)",
                data: myvalues
            }
        ]
    };




    var ctx = $("#canvas")[0].getContext("2d");
    var TestChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'radar',
        data: data,
        options: options
    });

    new Chart(ctx).Radar(data, options);

}
```

Comment: `You are declaring speed variable inside If scope.` - no the variable is in declared in the `window.test` function - fun with hoisting

Comment: Using the code above, I get "myvalues is not defined".

Comment: @Henning depanding on your context, you could move `var speed` out of the `window.test scope` and close `window.scope` after last `else if`

Comment: I have done that (edited code in my question). If I define speed in global scope, it shows the entered data. So the function to change var speed does not work. I don´t know why.

Comment: Where is the code for chart initialization? And you are declaring myvalues twice.

Comment: @Henning, try putting entire code inside window.test, and then call window.test to initialize your chart.

Comment: That´s the solution! WORKS! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Henning, I've updated my answer to suit your question with an explanation why your code did not update speed.

Answer (score -1):

Thats because you define speed in a if clause, therefore speed isn't defined when used.
You can look into it when using the debugger.
I would also use a switch statement, check out this

```js
var speed;
var myValues = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10];
document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = "myValues = ["+myValues+"]";

window.test = function(e) {
  //alert(e.value);
  switch (e.value) {
    case "Motor1":
      updateSpeed(50);
      break;
    case "Motor2":
      updateSpeed(30);
      break;
    case "Motor3":
      updateSpeed(90);
      break;
  }
};

updateSpeed = function(newSpeed) {
  var index = myValues.indexOf(speed);
  if (index > -1) {
    myValues.splice(index, 1);
  }
  speed = newSpeed;
  myValues.push(newSpeed);
  document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = "myValues = ["+myValues+"]";
}
```

```html
<select name="Motors" onchange="test(this);">
  <option selected="selected">Choose your motors</option>
  <option value="Motor1">Motor1</option>
  <option value="Motor2">Motor2</option>
  <option value="Motor3">Motor3</option>
</select>
<br>
<code id="data"></code>
```

Comment: `Thats because you define speed in a if clause` - it's actually because speed is declared in the `window.test` function and isn't available in the global scope where it is being pushed .... regardless - this code will ALSO push undefined as the first value in the array, and that value will **always** be undefined regardless of what speed is set to

Comment: Thats true too, but as I don't know what 'myvalues' is for a further explanation from @Henning would be welcome

Comment: So the data in "myvalues" should change according to the Motor selected?

Comment: My values provides data for a dataset, which is needed to create a diagramm with chart.js: 
      var data = {
       labels: ["Top-Speed",...],     datasets: [
 
  {
        ...,
            backgroundColor: "rgb(221, 221, 221)",
         data : myvalues 
  }
 ]  };

Comment: @GruberEDU Yep that´s it

Comment: Is it now the way you wish it?